# Virtual device and hardware profile for my target

Tags: android, samsung-mobile

Which virtual device and hw profile should I choose in Android Studio if I target the Samsung Galaxy S8 smartphones? I tried building an apk from the examples but it just crashes in the phone. In the emulator it works.

Comment: Sadly you need to test it in real device. So far Samsung only provided [this](http://developer.samsung.com/technical-doc/view.do?v=T000000095) and yet they never provided a solution for your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Design related issue you can use genymotion emulator

[image]

Otherwise, for crash,  you have to use Firebase Crash Reporting or other Crash Reporting library to solve crash